# How to create a background job for get request with Sidekiq and httparty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, worker

I need help developing a worker with sidekiq for this situation:

I have a helper that looks like this:

```
module UploadsHelper

    def save_image
        response = HTTParty.get(ENV['IMAGE_URI'])
        image_data = JSON.parse(response.body)
        images = image_data["rows"].map do |line|
            u = Image.new
            u.description = line[5]
            u.image_url = line[6]
            u.save
            u
        end
        images.select(&:persisted?)
    end

end
```

In my `app/views/uploads/index.html.erb` I just do this

```
<% save_image %>
```

Now, when a user visits the uploads/index page the images are saved to the database.

The problem is that the get request to the API is really slow. I want to prevent request timeouts by moving this to a background job with sidekiq.

This is my `workers/api_worker.rb`

```
class ApiWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform

  end

end
```

I just don't know the best way to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing this task using a Sidekiq worker implies that the task will run in async, and thus, it will not be able to return the response immediately, which is being sent by `images.select(&:persisted?)`.

First of all, instead of calling `save_image`, you need to call the worker's `perform_async` method.

```
<% ApiWorker.perform_async %>
```

This will enqueue a job in Sidekiq's queue (`your_queue` in this example). Then in worker's `perform` method, call the `save_image` method of `UploadsHelper`.

```
class ApiWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'your_queue'
  include UploadsHelper

  def perform
    save_image
  end
end
```

You may want to save the response of `save_image` somewhere. To get Sidekiq start processing the jobs, you can run `bundle exec sidekiq` from your app directory.

Comment: Exactly, except the method is `perform_async`.

Comment: @MikePerham Thanks for pointing it out. I just got it matched with a simple ActiveJob worker. :)

Comment: I have a follow up question on a porduction issue with the worker here in case you are interested thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756028/sidekiq-error-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory