# Heroku crash (seems to be Sidekiq / Redis )

Tags: redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I have the following issue when booting app on Heroku :

```
2018-02-20T23:55:19.456182+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml`
2018-02-20T23:55:20.180974+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-02-20T23:55:23.590432+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-78no8 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.2.10 with redis options {:url=>"redis://h:REDACTED@ec2-34-252-234-97.eu-west-1.compute
.amazonaws.com:27639"}
2018-02-20T23:55:24.455410+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-20T23:55:24.466303+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-02-20T23:55:24.271262+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2018-02-20T23:55:24.271106 #4]  INFO -- : DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: 1
2018-02-20T23:55:24.274465+00:00 app[worker.1]: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2018-02-20T23:55:24.274469+00:00 app[worker.1]:         Is the server running locally and accepting
2018-02-20T23:55:24.274471+00:00 app[worker.1]:         connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Seems to be a problem with redis but can't figure out what's wrong.

**sidekiq.yml**

```
development:
  :concurrency: 5
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

**Config vars**

```
REDIS_URL   redis://h:pe........stuff.here..........9fa3@ec2-34-252-234-97.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27639
```

**Redis.rb**

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
```

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: Well my problem was from the Sidekiq initializer file. I followed a tutorial on internet which provided 'faulty' code. I am replying to my question right now, you can try it...

Comment: I actually just found the answer - anyone in the future, this post solved my issue. It was not a bad configuration of the db at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813929/redistogo-and-sidekiq-on-heroku-cant-connect/49701613#49701613

Comment: Oh yes it can be a problem with Redis. But in my case Redis was ok. (I  tweaked everything possible with Redis before I found out the proble was the Sidekiq initializer ...)

Comment: Interesting. I was getting the same error on a PS db that has been running with no issues for over a year, so I knew the config wasn't wrong

Answer (score 1):

Read the error carefully:

> Is the server running locally and accepting
>   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Your database is misconfigured.

Comment: Thanks Mike. found a similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756028/sidekiq-error-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory but not really helpful. When I run console on my app, i can query the database though. I then guess the database can be properly configured but some access between different services not working properly ?

Comment: OK Heroku documentation mentions this very issue https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#troubleshooting it seems to be a "$path" problem. I have little knowledge of these kind of issues but will look further.

Comment: Ok fixed. I removed the block in my sidekiq config as per thread above. Now I get some error 'ERR max number of clients reached' and have come upon your explanation here Mike : https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/117 Is it still valid as written in 2012 ? And is there a good tutorial on the web for this ? I will write a new question in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of fixed the inital error message is changing my sidekiq.rb initalizer file to :

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 1}
  end
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL']}
  end
end
```